# Creating Google Analytics Property not using Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I went to create a new google analytics property for my mobile app, and it seems like Google is now forcing us to use their Firebase analytics for mobile. There is no option to not use Firebase if you select that you are creating the property for a mobile app.

Does anyone know a way around this? I need to create a new property for my app, and my app isn't set up to use Firebase.

Thanks!

Comment: Got the same issue :) very strange in: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/10/18/firebase-analytics-for-apps/ you can see the old way (screenshot) the google analytics option disappeared

Comment: Go to the bottom of the page and send FeedBack to the team so they know that you are not happy with this new implementation.

Answer (score 13):

Follow the below steps:

1. First create a property for website under PROPERTY column mentioning
   your mobile app website in website field. example "resApp.com/"
2. For this created property, create a new view under VIEW column by selecting "Mobile" from the dropdown menu.
3. By doing this you can get to use Google analytics alone. No need of firebase.

Check this link for reference : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en&visit_id=1-636317179632979567-126840879&rd=1

Comment: How could I register multiple apps for the same "website"? Should I add the same tracking code for each app?

Comment: this should be accepted

Answer (score 11):

You could also use this link to create a project or property :
https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

1. Here it will ask for your app name(TestApp) and bundle ID(com.test.app).
2. Then Click on Continue to Choose and Configure services
3. Choose Analytics
4. Immediately it will enable Analytics for your app and will show up the New Tracker ID and also the PROPERTY you are looking for.

Property created will bear a name in the combination of your App name and Bundle ID given in the first step (TestApp iOS/Android: com.test.app)

Comment: That doesnt exactly help i have a windows app

Comment: Looks like the link now redirects to Firebase...

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple way to achieve this by just creating a new account in your Google Analytic admin page, then you are allowed to create a moblie app tracker id with this account.

[image]

Comment: Google will only show firebase now if you attempt this

Comment: @efwjames, I just tried, this method is still existed.

Comment: Hmm maybe for some markets its different. It works if you select Website and then create a Mobile view later.